# Masking connected pixels less than certain area in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I've created an annual composite and used a clusterer to identify all ice in a mountain range in an attempt to analyze glacial health in Alaska. I want only the objects greater than 0.05 km^2. I tried the method suggested by Daniel Wiel from [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/360552/mask-out-pixels-smaller-than-1ha-in-google-earth-engine), as shown below:

```
var minArea = 500000;
var maxSize = 1024;
var pixelCount = iceMask.connectedPixelCount(maxSize);
var minPixelCount = ee.Image(minArea).divide(ee.Image.pixelArea()); 
iceMask = iceMask.updateMask(pixelCount.gte(minPixelCount));
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Output of image computation is too large (7 bands for 6267720 pixels = 167.4 MiB > 80.0 MiB).
If this is a reduction, try specifying a larger 'tileScale' parameter.
```

I tried adjusting the tileScale parameter, but even at the largest value (16), the same error occurs. How do I properly mask out all objects less than 0.05 km^2?

My code is [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/cdf48bc324b9ce2e8aa478fcd9349aa0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for this your best bet would be to transform your image into vectors, which outputs a featureCollection, and then filtering said featureCollection, like this:

```
 // Reduce to vectors
var icePatches = iceMask.reduceToVectors({scale: 200, geometry: geo, maxPixels:1e13}); //Scale must be smaller than sqrt(50000m2)
var err = ee.ErrorMargin(200); //Set error margin

  // Get patch areas
var addArea = function(feature) { //Function that computes the feature's geometry area and adds it as a property.
  var patchArea = ee.Number(feature.geometry(err).area(err).divide(1e6)); //Area in km2
  return feature.set({areaKm2: patchArea});
};

icePatches = icePatches.map(addArea); //Map the function over the FeatureCollection
print('totalIcePatches',icePatches.size());

var icePatchesFiltered = icePatches.filter(ee.Filter.gt('areaKm2', 0.05)); //Filter featureCollection
print('icePatchesFiltered',icePatchesFiltered.size());

var empty = ee.Image().byte();
var filledOutlines = empty.paint(icePatchesFiltered).paint(icePatchesFiltered, 0, 1);
Map.addLayer(filledOutlines, {palette: ['blue']}, 'Patches');
```

The calculation takes time but it works. Make sure the scale to which you reduce vectors is smaller than the square root of the minimum area you want to filter out.